# wrong x tick label matplotlib

Tags: dataframe, matplotlib

I got a [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt1lA.png).

I want to plot a bar chart from the dataframe using the following commands

```
ax0 = df_peakeffi.plot(kind='bar', width=0.8, figsize=(10, 4), hatch='/', edgecolor='black')
ax0.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=0)
```

However, it gave the wrong x tick label ([plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmciy.png))

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
ax0 = df_peakeffi.transpose().plot(kind='bar', 
      width=0.8, figsize=(10, 4), hatch='/', edgecolor='black')
```

Comment: By default the pandas `plot.bar` function takes the dataframe index as the x-axis for your plot. Check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) for a proper explanation